# MvcSiteMapProvider visibility doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider, asp.net-mvc-sitemap

I have a asp.net mvc 4 web application. and I use MvcSiteMapProvider to make my menu.
I set visibility attribute at mvcSiteMapNode. like :

```xml
 <mvcSiteMapNode title="Verify Email" action="Verify" visibility="SiteMapPathHelper,!*" visiable="SiteMapPathHelper,!*"></mvcSiteMapNode>
```

[Advanced Node Visibility with ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Advanced-Node-Visibility-with-ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider)

but I found it doesn't work.

Then I added FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider to my project for testing. I set a breakpoint to "node.Attributes.ContainsKey("visibility")" and found ISiteMapNode can't get attribute "visibility". but I tried to set a custom attribute (ex. visiable), It can be get.

How can I do for the visibility attribute ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in v4.4.7 that was fixed in [v4.4.8](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/releases/tag/v4.4.8) (see [issue #262](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/262)).

If you upgrade, the problem should go away. However, if you are still having problems, please open a [new issue @ Github](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/new).

Comment: Can you please help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751962/is-there-a-simple-way-to-control-the-visibility-of-individual-items-in-mvcsitema) question?